# Javascript: window.confirmation

Tags: javascript, html, confirm

I have a function:

```
function placeOrder(price, productList) {
    var bulletinBoardItem = Number(productList.box1.value);
    var stickersItem = Number(productList.box2.value);
    var cutoutsItem = Number(productList.box3.value);
    var trimmerItem = Number(productList.box4.value);
    var resourceBooksItem = Number(productList.box5.value);
    var price = new Array(5);
        price[0] = 12;
        price[1] = 1; 
        price[2] = 6;
        price[3] = 3;                       
        price[4] = 20; 
    var sumBB = bulletinBoardItem * price[0];
    var sumStickers = stickersItem * price[1];
    var sumCutouts = cutoutsItem * price[2];
    var sumTrimmer = trimmerItem * price[3];
    var sumRB = resourceBooksItem * price[4];
    }
```

and I have a window.confirm box that I need to reference the above function from, but none of the variables are recognized in that function.  I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here.

```
<input type="button" onClick="placeOrder()" value="Place Order">
    <p id = "order"></p>
<script>
function placeOrder(quantity, price, productList) {
var r = confirm("You've ordered Bulletin Boards");
if (r) {
    window.alert("Your order has been placed!!!")
} else {
    window.alert("Your order has been canceled.");
}
document.getElementById("order").innerHTML = txt;
}

</script>
```

Comment: You have shown two different functions that are both called `placeOrder()`, both of which have defined arguments that you don't supply when you call whichever one the `onclick` handler is trying to call. From the code shown I'm unclear about what you're trying to do. Are you saying you want the `confirm()` in the second `placeOrder()` function to display the value of the `sumBB` and/or other variables from the first `placeOrder()` function? Please [edit] your question to clarify. (I think step 1 of any solution would be to give your functions different names.)

Comment: That's where I'm confused.  I want to use the information from the first placeOrder function to make a window.confirm box

Comment: So where is the first `placeOrder()` called from? Is there any reason why you can't add the `confirm()` calls to the end of that first function? (If you do need two separate functions, please give them different names.)

Comment: can you do that is the heading?

Comment: The first function is in my original question, are you saying that I can place the confirm there?  How do I do that?  I tried that once and it failed.

Comment: Your question doesn't show how the first `placeOrder()` is *called*. But yes, if you want a call to that first function to include a confirmation prompt you can call `confirm()` from there - you'd just copy/move the code shown in your second function to the first.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is due in 45 minutes, and I did what you told me to and it didn't work.  I understand the theory, but can't seem to execute it.  I can't afford a bad grade....

Answer (score 0):

You are using `txt` which is not defined :

```
document.getElementById("order").innerHTML = txt;
```

Thus, try to change `txt` by any defined string and your script will not be failed

Comment: What does any defined string mean, sorry it's my 2nd semester

Comment: Try this `document.getElementById("order").innerHTML="I am Erica"` , then, you will understand